# Connect the app server to Akka on open shift algorithms server

Tags: java, akka, openshift

We changed our architecture from P2P servers to openstack. 
We have application server(Java Spark) and algorithms server(also Java, Akka).

The connection between them, happens from a frontend actor.

We have problem because now, unlike the past, we have NAT, in our new OS architecture.
It’s not peer to peer anymore.

The Error that appear:

```
[...FrontendActor/EndpointWriter] dropping message [class Akka.actor.ActorSelectionMessage] for non-local[actor[akka.tcp://....]] arrive at [...] inbound addresses are... .
```

.
I already tried to use floating IP, in the akka.remote.netty.tcp, but  it didn’t help to solve the problem.

I really need help, with what should we do different in the configuration file, the .conf of akka.
And if maybe we should config something in Open Stack.

Our Open stack architecture

Web -> router -> Network with all the algo servers instances.

[Our OpenStack architecture ][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/apMjF.jpg[image][image]

Comment: Can you share your akka configuration? Particularly the `bind` section

Comment: I Added the current configurations, to the post.